# How to check is dirty Functinality in xamarin forms and a show alert when click Back button

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I have one create page where the user can create the student details and it will be displayed in the list in next page and when we tap on one list view it will be going to editable or update screen in this case when the user has modified any of the field and clicks back button with out saving we should display a pop up "You will lost unsaved details" in MVVM. this is the scnerio please help in IsDirty functinality in xamarin forms.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: we are duplicateing the models by using clone and we are comparing  but it is not better approach

Comment: why it is not the best approach?

Comment: If you have any alternate way let me know

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Fody.PropertyChanged, you can add this to your view model:

```
public bool IsChanged{ get; set; }
```

And it will, in addition to calling the property changed handler, set the IsChanged field to true when any property on the view model is set.

Another option would be to serialize your model to a wire format like JSON  before and after and do a string compare.